# How to move multiple vertices forward until one lines up with plane (Autodesk Maya)

Tags: 3d, maya, modeling

I want to move the front face of a cylinder(-cone) so that the rightmost vertex hits the y-z-plane(the big black line in my image), but along the axis of the part. I tried making a new plane and making it a live surface, but that causes all vertices to stick to it.

Picture of my model, I want to move them in the direction of the yellow arrow:

[image: Picture of my model, I want to move them in the direction of the yellow arrow.]

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straight forward to do...

- When you have made your selection, you can change the pivot of the
  transform - default hotkey is D.
- Then use snap-to-vertex (hold V key)to snap the pivot to the
  right-most vertex.
- Press D again confirm the pivot change.
- Finally you can use snap-to-grid (hold X key) and only drag in the
  X-direction. Change your move tool to use world instead of object or
  component.